# Ansible win_lineinfile how to append to line

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to add value to a line and getting odd results.

**Original line (may change value):**

```
SomeParam=test
```

**Code:**

```
- name: Add info
  win_lineinfile:
   path: file_path
   backrefs: yes
   regexp: '(SomeParam=*)'
   line: '\1,added info'
```

**Result:**

```
\1,added info
```

**Expected result:**

```
SomeParam=test,added info
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here.

Firstly, in the Windows version of `lineinfile` (i.e. `win_lineinfile`), you need to use `$1` instead of `\1` as a back reference.

Secondly, your regular expression should be `(SomeParam=.*)` and not `(SomeParam=*)` -- the latter will match `SomeParam` followed by zero or more `=` signs, whereas the former will match `SomeParam=` followed by zero or more *characters*.

Taking into consideration the above, try the following:

```
- name: Add info
  win_lineinfile:
    path: file_path
    backrefs: yes
    regexp: '(SomeParam=.*)'
    line: '$1,added info'
```